# Why am I getting a page not found error after creating a new menu item?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-routes

In my module file I created a new menu item

```
function xmlproject_menu() 
{
  $items = array();

  //more items here

  $items['system/xml/cfa/initialize/%/%/%/%/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'xmlproject_initialize_cf',
    'page arguments' => array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8,),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function xmlproject_initialize_cf($session_id, $cart_id, $pid, $rid, $partner_id)
{
  //some code here
}
```

I have tried going to admin/build/modules, devel/menu/reset, and admin/settings/performance to clear the cache. I can see the menu item in the database (menu_router).
[image]

When I go to http://example.com/system/xml/cfa/initialize/1/2/3/4/5 I am getting "Page not found".

Answer (score 1):

You code seems all dandy, but I suppose your page callback "xmlproject_initialize_cf" should actually return something.

Try this:

```
function xmlproject_initialize_cf($session_id, $cart_id, $pid, $rid, $partner_id)
{
  // Your Code
  return 'Hello world!';
}
```

Is the modules name "xmlproject"?

Comment: that is not the problem,if a callback does not return any thing, page should be blank,bu the OP getting page not found

Answer (score 1):

Does not seems anything wrong with your code.
Just curious, why you have kept the last element of array as 'empty' (a comma after number 8)

```
'page arguments' => array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8,),
```

Also, there is additional empty item in the array (extra comma after MENU_CALLBACK)

```
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
```

Answer (score 1):

As you see in your database `number_part` column that contains Number of parts in router path,sets to 7(maximum available part),but your parts of menu callback is 9.Which is more than  [MENU_MAX_PARTS](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/constant/MENU_MAX_PARTS/6) available in drupal 6. this is why you're getting `Page not found`
Just reduce your menu item size and you are good to go.for example:

```
$items['initialize/%/%/%/%/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'xmlproject_initialize_cf',
    'page arguments' => array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
 );
```